# Get URL of link clicked in a web view swift

Tags: swift, uiwebview

I load a html page from url in a `UIWebView` in Swift and I would like to know how I can get the URL of a link in my html after click to load a new page. After some search I found something like `shouldStartLoadWithRequest` and `LinkClicked` but it's not really helpful.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

I used WKWebView and with some script I inject some CSS so no need to get url after click.

Comment: You didn't ask how to inject some CSS, you asked how to get the URL. While your solution worked for your purposes, it doesn't answer your question. You should've deleted this question back in September of '15 - now that there's a working answer by @DG7 - you should accept that

Answer (score 5):

I know late to the response, but I think this may be what you're looking for. request.URL! gives you the URL to whatever was clicked.

```
func webView(webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWithRequest request: NSURLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {

    let scheme = request.URL!
        NSLog(scheme)


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use This Code : Suppose url to be linked is (www.google.com)

```
func webView(_ webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWith request: URLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {

let urlString = request.url?.absoluteString
print(urlString)        //  "www.google.com"
return true
}
```